# How to configure mismatch types in model mapper for protobuf builder in java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, modelmapper, protobuf-java

I am trying to map my business model to protobuf pojo and I am getting below exception

`Cannot map final type com.xxx.xxx.xx.xx.proto.xxx$Builder` ,

I have registered `ProtobufModule` for `Modelmapper` bean like below

```
 ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new ProtobufModule());
```

and tried to address custom mappings like below

```
TypeMap<BusModel, com.xxx.proto.xxx.Builder> typeMap =
            mapper.createTypeMap(BusModel.class, com.xxx.proto.xxx.Builder.class);
        typeMap .addMappings(map -> map.map(BusModel::getAttrType, com.xxx.proto.xxx.Builder::setMismatchAttrType));
```